# javascript issue in sharepoint

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having issues making a `javascript` work. Basically i just use this script for different web parts which have the `.q1table` class to insert some other classes.

I am getting an error uncaught type error Property $ of object[object window] is not a function.This works fine when the page is in normal mode but in edit mode it throws error.

can some one please tell me what am i doing wrong here.

```
 jQuery('.q1Table tr').each(function (index) {

   var $wp = $(this).find('tr:first');  ---this line throws the error

   var $1TR = $wp.closest('tr');
   $1TR.addClass("TitleBar");
   $1TR.removeClass('ms-Header');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I can't garantee if this (only) solves your problem. At least this can be a tip for using jQuery within SharePoint.

One should avoid using $ for jQuery in SharePoint. It can conflict with SharePoint's other javascript objects like cmssitemanager as described in my blog post [$ in cmssitemanager.js conflicts with $ in jQuery](http://sharepointkunskap.wordpress.com/2012/06/01/in-cmssitemanager-js-conflicts-with-in-jquery/)

I often disable $ for jQuery by running:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Then only jQuery is available and $ doesn't conflict with SharePoint's $ objects. Hopefully, Microsoft won't use $ in their javascript code in the future.

Comment: I also think this could help. I usually replace every $ with jQuery, for example jQuery(this).find('tr') instead of $(this).find('tr')

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint has very specific instances where the $ namespace collides with one of SharePoint's JavaScript includes when you are in Page Edit mode and also in rare instances of FAST Search.

`jQuery.noConflict();` is a great option, but you have to be careful when using it - if any other web parts are using jQuery and they reference the `$(...)` instead of `jQuery(...)`, their code will stop functioning.

I have an [article on my blog](http://www.stephanrocks.com/2012/03/17/jquerys-vs-jquery-and-why-you-should-use-jquery-noconflict/) that deals with the jQuery.noConflict().

Another fun and safe way I've been using jQuery is by utilizing your own namespace:

```
$mine = jQuery.noConflict();
$mine('#myId').fadeIn();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use only first TR from your table. You can try other approach in JQuery which may be useful, like:

$(".q1Table tr:nth-child(1)").addClass("TitleBar");

$(".q1Table tr:nth-child(1)").removeClass('ms-Header');